# php cannot GET mysql results from url with special characters or spaces?

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I have been trying to fix this issue for 2 days now with no avail.

basically, I am trying `$_GET` results from mysql based on whatever is in the URL passed on from the previous page.

the url is like this: `http://mydomain.com/manufacturer/abc`

to achieve this URL, i am using `.htaccess` which works fine.

but if the url has an `empty space` or a `-` or any other special characters, my php file won't GET the results from the mysql database.

so this won't work:

`http://mydomain.com/manufacturer/a-b-c`

or this won't work:

`http://mydomain.com/manufacturer/a b c`

nor does this:

`http://mydomain.com/manufacturer/a+bc`

etc etc....

I am using smarty which so far was a very straight forward process but now that it has come to this, it has proven to be a bit difficult.

my php file looks like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['man'])) {
$man = $_GET['man'];
if( ! $stmt = $db_conx->prepare("SELECT id, man, product_name FROM `$TabelName` WHERE `man` = ?") ) {
  die( $db_conx->error );
}

$stmt->bind_param('s', $man);
if ( ! $stmt->execute() ) {
  die( $stmt->error );
}
$stmt->bind_result($id, $man, $product_name);
$stmt->store_result();

while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $value[] = array('id'=>$id, 'man'=>$man, 'product_name'=>$product_name);
}
}


// Assign this array to smarty...
$smarty->assign('man', $value);



// Assign this array to smarty...
$smarty->assign('$man', $value);

}
```

**and this is my htaccess file:**

```
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^manufacturer/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ manufacturers.php?manu=$1
RewriteRule ^manufacturer/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ manufacturers.php?manu=$1
```

I have tried `urlencode` and `urldecode` in every which way possible, and nothing seemed to work.

could someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your RewriteRule prohibits anything but letters and numbers.

Comment: `$_GET['man']` but in your .htaccess you have `?manu=$1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this:

```
RewriteRule ^manufacturer/(.*)/?$ manufacturers.php?manu=$1
```

Note the `/?`, you don't need the second rule, this thing does it for you.

Comment: your answer does exactly what i need. so thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

DO

`RewriteRule ^manufacturer/(.+)/?$ manufacturers.php?manu=$1`

Which means anything one or more times after manufacturer/ gets matched.